# Where do I need to put the extra semicolon on line 17

Tags: c, gcc

I'm new to programming in C and I'm trying to create a program that when a user inputs their name, they are told what their sexual orientation is randomly. Yet, gcc is erroring because I think I am missing a ; on line 17 which is: if(strcmp(x, arrayNames[i] == 0));. I am not too familiar with strcmp(); but I am reading about it in K&R, just can't get my head around it. Below is the entire code:

```
int main()
{
    char *arrayNames[3]={"Jim", "Bob", "Dave"};
    char *arrayOrient[3]={"straight", "gay", "bi"};
    char x[100];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int size;
    size = sizeof(arrayNames)/sizeof(arrayNames[0]);
    int namesRand = rand() % size;

    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &x[0]);
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(x, arrayNames[i] == 0));
        {
            printf("Hello %s, your orientation is: %s", x, arrayOrient[namesRand]);
        break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid name!");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any tips when using strcmp(); will be welcomed.

Comment: remove ; from the if statement

Comment: And format your code so you can see where the `{}` characters belong.

Comment: And move the `)` in the `if` statement to after `arrayNames[i]`.

Comment: Please remove the wayward semicolon, properly place the `)`, recompile, and quote here the EXACT error message (if any) the compiler returns.

Comment: $gcc main.c -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:6:16: error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:6:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:11:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]
main.c:12:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'scanf' [enabled by default]

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to remove the semicolon. No need for a semicolon in an if then statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error.  Here is what that line *should* be:

```
if(strcmp(x, arrayNames[i]) == 0)
```

See the extra ")" that you need after "`arrayNames[i]`"?  [Strcmp compares two arguments](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) and returns "0" if the two strings are the same.

Remove the extra "`);`" (parents and unnecessary semi-colon) at the end of the "if" line.

Comment: It isn't syntax error, its valid code! Maybe not that usefull but absolutly no syntax error!

Comment: Thanks for the down vote @Zaibis; by syntax error, I meant the "`strcmp(X,Y)`" is the error, not the semi colon.  "`strcmp(X,Y==0)`" is comparing string X to the evaluated -- and Boolean -- result of Y equaling zero.

Comment: who says i voted down? put look whats wrong with it? both: x and array[i] are zero terminated char arrays, so whats the syntax error?

Comment: @Zaibis - Yet of the answers so var, Michael's the only one to identify the real problem.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks; they'll eventually come around.

Comment: uh damn :x eddit your post plz, i have to un down vote :x but anyway that wasnt his question so rage downvoting isnt the fine way too.

Comment: Just by the way, even then its not an syntax error, its an runtime error, because the string will be unequal 0, so he will be passing the NULL adress into the function whats anyway vallid (more or less)

Comment: Interestingly `if(strcmp(x, arrayNames[i] == 0));` does cause a syntax error.  The syntax error occurs because the `if()` gets closed and the `else` block has no proceeding `if()`.  By changing to this post's `if(strcmp(x, arrayNames[i]) == 0)`, the `else` syntax error is resolved and the code does what is more likely wanted.

Comment: And that's exactly what I posted and what I got down-voted for.

Comment: Don't get that, ofc the not matching else is an syntax error, but replacing the brace shiuldn't prevent of an syntax error, should it? if so, because of what?!

Comment: Appreciate the help, Michael. I will update my code when I'm back at home and update you with the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code is not compiling is that this is a complete statement

```
if(strcmp(x, arrayNames[i] == 0))
    ; // If the strings are the same, do an empty expression.
```

Obviously the statement should be:

```
if(0 == strcmp(x, arrayNames[i]))
```

Now we have a block of code with an else without an if. So the compiler complains.

```
{
} else // This else doesn't match the if, the if is a single-line statement.
```

Try this:

```
if(0 == (strcmp(x, arrayNames[i])))
{
    printf("Hello %s, your orientation is: %s", x, arrayOrient[namesRand]);
    break;
}
else {
        printf("Invalid name!");
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the output once changing to your recommended code: main.c:18:9: error: expected ')' before '{' token
main.c:25:1: error: expected expression before '}' token

Comment: @zacsteele Sorry I did not see your comment earlier. I fixed the typo. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you put an semicolon behind an `if` statement as in this case:

(I'm not refering to the wrong placed brace as others did I just want to clarify the use of a semicolon)

```
if(strcmp(x, arrayNames[i] == 0));
{
    printf("Hello %s, your orientation is: %s", x, arrayOrient[namesRand]);
    break;
        }
    else {
        printf("Invalid name!");
    }
}
```

The standard says if u don't place braccets for a jump statement (as loops or an if statement)
, then the scope is just the next expression.

So what happens is: the `if` statement is refering to the semicolon`;` what means, if the statement is true, nothing will be executed. As there is no expression associated with the semicolon, so the statement is already invoked, and the embraced scope is executed in any case, undependend of the `if` statement.

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense. Thank you Zaibis.

Answer (score 0):

Zaibis and Dauterman and Hot Licks are correct.  Plus:
 1. I have also added newlines to the end of the printf, the "**\n**".
 2. In addition, this macro will make your life easier:

```
#define strEQ(a,b) (0 == strcmp((a),(b)))

...
if(strEQ(x, arrayNames[i]) {
    printf("Hello %s, your orientation is: %s\n", x, arrayOrient[namesRand]);
    break;
} else {
    printf("Invalid name!\n");
}
```

This is a pretty strange program, that let's users guess a name but not choose their sexual orientation!  And how are they supposed to know which of the three names are acceptable?

Also, you have a *potential* bug here:
          arrayOrient[namesRand]

In that the number namesRand was chosen using the length of the other array, arrayNames, instead of the length of arrayOrient.

Comment: the program is supposed to let the user enter their name, then randomly generate their sexual orientation. It is just a bit of fun, my friend.